# fread into while loop - can't clean output buffer

Tags: php

I'm downloading a large file like that:

```
$fd = fopen($url, "r");

while(!feof($fd))
{
    echo fread($fd, 4096);
    ob_flush(); 
    flush();
}
```

But I have one problem - the file is downloading only to 11,6 MB and stop... 
Where is a problem? I'm using ob_flush and flush so I think - it should work.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you set the `max_execution_time` ini value to `0` ?

Comment: I set this: set_time_limit(0)

Comment: Hmm. It should work. Have you tried `readfile()` like I suggested in my answer?

Comment: Can I use readfile with URLs? If I use readfile - I should clean output buffor or set max ex. time ?

Comment: Set max execution time to `0`, don't use output buffering.

Comment: When I try use readfile(), I don't get any response. Script always "buffering" but don't get any response.

Comment: No, I just change code from my first post for: set_time_limit(0); readfile($url); That's all.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `fread()` loop if you just want to output a remote file. You can use:

```
readfile($url);
```

That's it. However, the script you showed should work as well. The reason must be on the remote server.

If the download takes long you should consider to set the execution time to unlimited:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

... on top of your script.

Comment: When I try use readfile(), I don't get any response. Script always "buffering" but don't get any response.

Comment: You need to disable output buffering

Comment: Do not enable it (also take care of php.ini)

Comment: I don't have permissions to edit php.ini. I can edit only .htaccess or set a few options like that: set_time_limit...

Comment: You can't use `set_time_limit()` in `.htaccess`

Comment: I know. What I mean is - I can edit only htaccess or a few options in PHP script like set_time_limit.

Comment: can you create a simple php file containing only `<?php set_execution_time(0); readfile('http://server/file');` ?